# Laravel 5.7 Login with no Redirect or Errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm new to Laravel so I started following lessons on Laracast then the guy who gave the lessons went to the authentication of a user and guessed etc.  The register works fine and it goes into the databases with hashed passwords and it keeps that user that just registered login (and can do all the stuff a login user is supposed to be doing on the website). When I go to my login form and try to log in it doesn't redirect and give errors. It just reloads even when user/password credentials are not correct.

It's needed to register how it saves the user into the database.

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => request('name'),
    'email' => request('email'),
    'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
]);
```

**login form...**

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
    @include ('layouts.errors')
</form>
```

**web.php for routing**

```
 Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
 Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
 Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
 Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

 Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');

 Route::get('/register', 'RegistrationController@create');
 Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');
 Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@create')->name('login');
 Route::post('/login', 'SessionsController@store');
 Route::get('/logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');
```

**The controller that handles the login**

```
<?php

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('sessions.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        // Attempt to authenticate the user.
        if (!auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
            return back();
        }
        // Redirect them to the homepage
        return redirect()->home();
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->home();
    }
}
```

**Errors.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="alert alert-errors">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li> {{ $error }} </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you run `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate` as stated in [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)?

Comment: No because hes making a custom login to explain it better how it works in laravel etc

Comment: What is your `home` page?

Comment: / i will edit the post whit all the routes

Comment: You don’t need to `bcrypt` the password yourself, the auth system does that for you. You’re probably getting an incorrect password error.

Comment: Its a custom build login if i dont add the bcrypt it will exactly put password into the database i already tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your form. 
The names of the inputs are the one that are needed in the controller to access them.

In the form you declared *Email* and *password*.

```
 ...
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" required>
....
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
...
```

In the Controller you try to access *email* and *password*.

```
if (! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
```

This might be the reason why the login fails and you just got redirected to the Page, because the executed code is

```
return back();
```

So change your form to

```
     ....

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="Email">Email:</label>

        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>

    </div>
    .....
```

Let me know if this is working.